# PNG file lifted from website for business card

Tags: print-design, png, print-production

I am doing a business card for my dad, and he has a website with the logo I'm going to use. Can i copy this image straight off the website as a .png file, or will this not translate nicely when it is printed? i.e. raster, etc?

If that will not be suitable, what should I actually be doing when I make the card in adobe InDesign? i.e. to get the best print production of the card in terms of this logo?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A PNG logo saved from a website will most likely not work for a printed business card. Have you tried actually designing the card and printing it on any home printer to see what it looks like? Most likely it will be printing as an unsharp/pixelated image.

In which case you would have to locate the original vector artwork for the logo, or just have it completely redrawn in a vector format (AI, EPS, etc).

PNG is generally not a print format, it could be in some cases if saved large enough, but generally PNG's are used for non-print work, mostly web assets.

Comment: Oh yeah ok. No I have not printed it. Good idea though. I will ask about the original artwork then. Thanks @Lucian